# Dynamically allocate an array of specified size in C

Tags: c, arrays, input, malloc

I need to create an array that's size is determined by user input, and then has pointers to said array.  All the array will hold is random numbers between 500-600.  I can't seem to use malloc correctly.  I am still new to C, so help is appreciated.

```
int main(){
        int size;
    printf("Enter size of array");
    scanf("%d", &size);


    int array[size];
    int *aPtr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * array);
```

Comment: Please don't cast the return value of malloc in C - it can hide problems that you don't want hidden. C is perfectly capable of changing a void* to any other pointer implicitly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You only need:

```
int *aptr = malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

and then you can access it just like an array.

```
aptr[0] = 123;
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably wanted to write:

```
int *aPtr = (int *) malloc(sizeof(int) * size);
```

You don't need that `array` variable anyway. You can index `aPtr` like `aPtr[10]`. Also don't forget `free(aPtr)` at the end.